# Automatic proofs using Isabelle HOL

Tags: logic

I'm starting to learn Isabelle but I have the following problem: I can't find any help regarding the use of its language. Everything I've seen so far is way to advanced for me to start from zero. I'd like to have something that would explain the behavior of the program, how it 'thinks'. That would sometimes explain the mentality of the programmers when they first needed the program to respond to an input by the user, and how they thought this input should be written. Something that would describe the thought process involved in the making of the program. Right now, for me, it's just a game of guessing, and I keep hammering myself with the question: why, why, why. It's a never-ending why. And the feeling of learning like this is not nice; the road is way too bumpy to enjoy the ride.

Comment: [Doumentation](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/documentation.html) is available...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. That question is off-topic here.

Comment: See also [Wiki's entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isabelle_(proof_assistant)) with link to the [Tutorial](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/techreports/UCAM-CL-TR-189.pdf)

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'll give that a try. Maybe it's just a matter to stop moaning, and putting the work.

Comment: IMO it is not an issue of "mentality of the programmers": you have to learn the syntax of the language and the specifications about the way to formalize the input.